# Error: iptables: No chain/target/match by that name

Tags: linux, iptables

I am trying to configure proxy server on RHEL Server 6.5 using Squid and iptables. Below is the command I executed and the error message it displayed:

```
vzlptest01 root [root] > iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
```

Some more details:

```
vzlptest01 root [root] > cat /proc/net/ip_tables_matches
limit
state
length
ttl
tcpmss
multiport
multiport
tos
tos
dscp
icmp
udplite
udp
tcp

vzlptest01 root [root] > cat /proc/net/ip_tables_targets
DNAT
SNAT
LOG
TOS
TOS
DSCP
TCPMSS
REJECT
ERROR
```

How to deal with this issue?

Comment: Please, add the output of `iptables-save` to your question.

Comment: `iptables-save`? Why?

Comment: OK, don't add it. Just check the names of the chains in a default RHEL installation.

Comment: Would I be right in thinking from the hostname this is an OpenVZ container, or some similar Virtuozzo-style virtual host?

Comment: It is a Parallels Virtuozzo container.

Comment: Don't even bother.  Virtuozzo is not virtualisation, merely containerisation, and the shared kernel makes it very subject to this particular issue; see eg http://serverfault.com/questions/608348/iptables-not-installed-on-centos/608509#608509 , and many other similar questions and answers on SF.  I'd vote to close this as a duplicate of that question, but it has no accepted answer; so I'll VTC as off-topic (virtuozzo just elevated itself to not-professional-sysadmin in my eyes, at least when used as a virtualisation solution).

Comment: We have many duplicates for this question; I've chosen one I could find easily.

Comment: make sure there is xt_nat.ko in your system, which is build by turn on CONFIG_IP_NF_NAT and CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_NATin kernel configuration

Answer (score 7):

It looks like you don't have a INPUT table. You could try creating it with

```
iptables -N INPUT
```

If that does't work than I would look at the virtualization technology in use and speak to the hosting provider about it.

As an aside

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

You almost certainly don't want to do that with a `-A`, `-I` would be much better in nearly all circumstaces.

Comment: I am reasonably sure that you dont create those chains, they exist by default as part of the filter table.

Comment: @Iain- I have successfully executed `iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT`, indicating that INPUT chain was already existing.

Comment: I am going to lay the blame at the feet of the virtualization technology your VPS is using then. You will need to speak to your hosting provider.